# I have convert Vue2 to Vue3 but I have Vutify error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, upgrade

**I have to convert my Vue2 to Vue3 project along with Electron (Desktop application)**

```
Vue Version: "^3.3.4",
Vuetify: "^3.4.0-beta.1",
```

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.mjs 101:29
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (101:29)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
| function inject(key) {
|   const vm = this.$;
>   const provides = vm.parent?.provides ?? vm.vnode.appContext?.provides;
|   if (provides && key in provides) {
|     return provides[key];
```

Comment: If anyone faces this issue please guide me, on how to resolve this.

Comment: Look at the vuetify installation method for Vue 3: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/

Comment: This is very to your setup, which is unknown

Answer (score 0):

Please check this URL - https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/
Follow the instructions of installation with vue 3.

Moreover, the error it seems to be specific to your environment, how ever you can consider also to remove the package and init again.

Comment: package means **Node Module** folder? or **package.json?**